# Not able to use protocol as key in dictionary in swift

Tags: enums, protocols, swift2

I am developing a functionality for two subsets of single type. eg. fruits. I have two enums for fruits as below:

```
enum SourFruits: String {
    case Grape, Orange, Lemon
}

enum SweetFruits: String {
    case Watermelon, Banana, Apple
}
```

To use these two as single type in my implementation I am using a protocol:

```
protocol Fruits {
}
extension SweetFruits: Fruits {
}
extension SourFruits: Fruits {
}
```

Now here is my implementation looks like:

```
func doCommonOnFruit(fruit: Fruits) {
    //Do common
}
func doSomeThingWithSourFruit(fruit: SourFruits) {
    doCommonOnFruit(fruit)
    // Do specific
}
func doSomeThingWithSweetFruit(fruit: SweetFruits) {
    doCommonOnFruit(fruit)
    // Do specific
}
```

This works fine but when I try to add it in a map as key:

```
let map: [Fruit : String] = [:]
```

It prompt me an error says: `Type 'Fruit' does not confirm to protocol 'Hashable'`. My map should contain any (sweet or sour fruit as key). How to achieve this.

I tried to implement `Hashable` in Fruit but it didn't worked. Please help me in this.

Comment: `I tried to implement Hashable in Fruit but it didn't worked` You should us what you've tried. Implementing Hashable is the way to go, maybe you did something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use protocol here- protocols are not actually of any type..its just definition. same thing can be achieved through class.

```
 class Fruits : NSObject {
    }
```

Now define, Subclass of Fruits. You can enum have as part of subclass.

```
class SweetFruits: Fruits  {
    enum SweetFruits: String {
        case Watermelon, Banana, Apple
    }


}
class SourFruits: Fruits {
    enum SourFruits: String {
        case Grape, Orange, Lemon
    }

}
```

in common method you can access it as following ...

```
func doCommonOnFruit(fruit: Fruits) {

    if(fruit.isKind(of: SourFruits.classForCoder()))
    {

    }
    if(fruit.isKind(of: SweetFruits.classForCoder()))
    {

    }
    //Do common
}
func doSomeThingWithSourFruit(fruit: SourFruits) {
    doCommonOnFruit(fruit: fruit)
    // Do specific
}
func doSomeThingWithSweetFruit(fruit: SweetFruits) {
    doCommonOnFruit(fruit: fruit)
    // Do specific
}
```

//You can directly use Enum with class name as below.

```
func test()
{
    let map: [Fruits : String] = [:]
    let  test  = SourFruits.SourFruits.Grape
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If protocol 'Fruits' conforms to protocol 'Hashable' it can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements.